Maximal elements of set with respect to partial order on $\mathbb{N}_0^2$
I might ask a trivial question, but it's been confusing me a bit.
Suppose $(P,\leq)$ is a partially ordered set, and let $S=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}\subset P$. Am I right to define $\max(S)$ - the set of maximal elements of $S$ as $\{m\in S: \forall p\in S(p\geq m \Rightarrow p=m)\}$, rather than $\{m\in P: \forall p\in S(p\geq m \Rightarrow p=m)\}$?
Let $\mathbb{N}_0 = \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$, and let $r\geq 2$. Define the following partial order on $\mathbb{N}_0^r$: $(x_1,\dots,x_r)\leq (y_1,\dots,y_n)$ if $x_i\leq y_i$ for every $i\in \{1,\dots,n\}$.
Consider the set $A=\{x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq (1,2), x\geq(2,1)\}$. By the definition of $\leq$, one can show that $A=\{(x_1,x_2)\in \mathbb{N}_0^2:x_1\geq 2, x_2\ge2\}$.
Initially, I thought that $A=\{x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq \max((1,2), (2,1))\}$, but the set $\{(1,2), (2,1)\}$ actually has two maximal elements: $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$.
What is wrong with my reasoning? I mean, is there something incorrect when I write $A=\{x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq \max((1,2), (2,1))\}$?

$\max(S)$ almost invariably means the maximum, not the set of maximals.

@ArturoMagidin, But can we define $\max(S)$ when $S\subset P$, where $P$ is a poset?

You can define the set of maximal elements of $S$ (though you should say that you mean "maximal in $S$", as opposed to maximal elements of $P$ that are in $S$). But you should not use notation that means something else to denote it.

@ArturoMagidin, sorry I am a bit confused by the wording: what is the difference between "maximal in $S$" and "maximal elements of $P$ that are in $S$"?

"maximal in $S$" mean maximal relative to the partial order on $S$ induced by $P$. It means the $m\in S$ such that for all $x\in S$, if $m\leq x$ then $m=x$. "maximal of $P$ that is in $S$" means $m\in S$ such that for all $x\in P$, if $m\leq x$ then $m=x$. That is, $m$ is in $S$, and is maximal in the set $P$. For example, say $P={a,b,c,d}$ with $a\lt b\lt c$, and $a\lt d$, and no other strict order relations. And let $S={b,d}$. Then $b$ is maximal in $S$, and $d$ is maximal in $S$; and $d$ is also a maximal element of $P$ that is in $S$. But $b$ is not.

Your first set, ${m\in P\mid \forall p\in S(p\geq m\to p=m)}$ is the set of elements of $P$ that are maximal in $P$ under the induced order. The second set isn't. ${m\in P\mid \forall p\in S(p\geq m\to p=m)}$ includes every strict upper bound to elements of $S$, as well as any element that is not comparable to anything in $S$, in addition to the maximal elements of $S$. Take $P={1,2,3,}$, where $1,2,3$ are in their usual order, and $$ is not comparable to anything. If $S={1,2}$, then your first set is ${2}$, and your second set is ${2,3,*}$.

@ArturoMagidin, thank you very much! I think I understand it. However, I am still wondering about my second question: if $A={x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq (1,2), x\geq (2,1)}$ then by the definition of $\leq$, we can show that $A={x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq (2,2)}$. But why can't we write it like $A={x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq \max((1,2),(2,1))}$? Here by $\max((1,2),(2,1))$ I denote the maximum of set ${(1,2),(2,1)}$ but such maximum does not exists. What is wrong here? Thank you!

By "maximum of the set", do you still mean "set of maximal elements"? If so... you have not defined what it means to be greater than or equal to a set. You would need to say $\forall s (s\in\max((1,2),(2,1))\to s\leq x)$ instead.

@ArturoMagidin, Sorry, I mean the greatest element of the set. For example, if we consider the usual ordering in $\mathbb{R}$, then $x\geq a$, $x\geq b$ iff $x\geq \max(a,b)$. I am trying to use the same reasoning here.

There is no "greatest element of the set ${(1,2),(2,1)}$". The two elements are incomparable. So if $\max((1,2),(2,1))$ is supposed to mean "the greatest element of the set ${(1,2),(2,1)}$. then it means nothing. It is nonsense notation, which makes any use of it incorrect. It would be like writing "$\max{x\in\mathbb{R}\mid 0\lt x\lt 1}$." It doesn't exist.

@ArturoMagidin, yeah I agree. So writing ${x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq (1,2), x\geq (2,1)}={x\in \mathbb{N}_0^2: x\geq \max((1,2), (2,1))}$ does not make sense, right? Becuase $\max((1,2),(2,1))$ does not exists. I just wanted to be sure. But we can do this if we have the total ordering on the set, right?

You can do it if $\max(S)$ makes sense for your set $S$. If you replace ${(1,2),(2,1)}$ with ${(2,2),(1,2),(2,1)}$, it would make sense because that set does have a maximum.

Yeah, indeed! I was just confused. Thank you very much for your explanation and patience! It's been good to learn these interesting facts about order theory. I didn't know it very well.
